# C# UWP: copy file to folder inside local folder not functioning properly

Tags: c#, file-io, uwp

I am currently building a music library application that will store and display music files.

The application will allow the user to press a button and then upload an audio file. I have written code to copy a music file from the user's computer into a music folder inside the local folder that I have created. My code seems to run fine with no apparent errors, however, when looking inside the application's folders, I do not see the musicfolder or file that has been placed in it.

Here's my code for `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace MusicLibraryTest
{   
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    { 
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Music Library is opened on user's computer and displays all available mp3 files    
            var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker
            {
                ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
                SuggestedStartLocation =  Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary
            };

            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".m4a");

            var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            var musicFolder = await folder.CreateFolderAsync("musicfolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

            //put file in future access list so it can be accessed when application is closed and reopened
            Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(file);
            //File is copied to local folder for use in music library
            if (folder != null && file != null)
            {
                await file.CopyAsync(musicFolder, file.Name, NameCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code from `MainPage.xaml`:

```
<Page
    x:Class="MusicLibraryTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MusicLibraryTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Add Music" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="750,407,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

It's probably a simple fix, but is there anything apparent in my code that would not allow the folder creation or file to be copied over?

Comment: Are you checking `LocalState\musicfolder` or somewhere else? I can tell your code is correct, I can see the file copied to that folder. Just in case, this folder locates in `%localappdata%\Packages\PACKAGENAME\LocalState`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the wrong place. I guess you are looking at the bin folder of the project.

The app needs to be deployed before it gets started, and its `LocalFolder` is located at

> %localappdata%\Packages\PACKAGENAME\LocalState

Where the **PACKAGENAME** is the package family name in the form of

> YourApp_8wekyb3d8bbwe

Which you can check in the `.appxmanifest` of the project, under the `Packaging` tab.

Answer (score 0):

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59133101/7534013), hope this helps you.

In this, you change from `openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");` to `openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");`. If you want accept all files then u simply write this line of code `openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");`

It's working fine from my side.
Thanks!!!